# Best way to pass value from component to other component's redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a question about passing value (item.id) from one component to another component's saga, where I could add additional field in POST body and make a request.

I have two components: 1st Form component, where is two input fields. 2st component is Item, which are GET'ed from API. So there is a itemId value, which I need to give when making POST request with form.

My soliution right now is to pass itemId to localstorage and then take it in saga, but it causes some bugs when user opens two browser windows. What would be better solution for this task?

My Item component:

```
export class FindClientItem extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false,
    };

    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
    localStorage.removeItem('itemId');
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;

    if(this.state.modalIsOpen){
     localStorage.setItem('itemId',item.itemId);
    }

    // Put together the content of the repository
    const content = (
      <Wrapper>
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        Details: {item.description}...<button onClick={this.openModal}>
          More
        </button>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Modal"
        >
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
          Details: {item.description} <br />
          <button onClick={this.openBidModal}>Submit</button>{' '}
        </Modal>
      </Wrapper>
    );

    // Render the content into a list item
    return <ListItem key={`items-${item.itemId}`} item={content} />;
  }
}
```

And then my other 1st Form component's saga:

```
export function* submitForm() {
  try {
    const formType = 'item';
    const body = yield select(makeSelectModifiedData());
    body.itemId = localStorage.getItem('itemId');
    let requestURL;

    switch (formType) {
      case 'item':
        requestURL = 'http://localhost:1234/item';
        break;
      default:
    }
    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, { method: 'POST', body });
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.error('Error message...', {
      html: false,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If these components are relational(parent-children), then you can pass the itemId as props otherwise store it into the redux store and fetch it from the redux store while submitting the form and pass it to the API call.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "Best" way to do this, however, works well for me. Have you tried creating a shared js file (imported into both components) which GETS / SETS a variable? for example.

**shared.js**

```
let data = null;

setData(d){
    data = d;
}

getData(){
    return data;
}

addChangeListner(eventName, callback){
    this.on(eventname, callback);
}

dispatcherCallback(action){
    switch(action.actionType){
         case 'SET_DATA':
         this.getData();
    }
}
```

Whenever you require your component to update, you can add an change listener to then return the new data once set so the components aren't out of sync. Just remember to remove the listener afterwords!

**Component**

```
componentDidMount(){
    shared.addChangeListner('SET_DATA', this.onUpdate)
}

// use x to pass to your saga...
onUpdate(){
    var x = shared.getData();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it changes data same as storing in localStorge. So it is bad solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

**index.js**

```
import {handleSave, loadData } from './action';
import Modal from './Modal',

export class GetFormData extends React.PureComponent {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadData();
  }

  saveData = (data) => {
     this.props.handleSave(data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Modal"
          data={this.props.getdata}
         handlePost={this.saveData}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  getdata: state.formData,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loadData: bindActionCreators(loadData, dispatch),
  handleSave: bindActionCreators(handleSave, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GetFormData);
```

**actions.js**

```
import {
  LOAD_DATA,
  LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
  LOAD_DATA_FAILED
  HANDLE_SAVE,
  HANDLE_SAVE_SUCCESS,
  HANDLE_SAVE_FAILED
} from './constants';

export function loadData() {
  return {
    type: LOAD_DATA,
  };
}

export function loadDataSuccess(formData) {
  return {
    type: LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
    formData
  };
}

export function loadDataFailed(error) {
  return {
    type: LOAD_DATA_FAILED,
    error
  };
}

export function handleSave(data) {
  return {
    type: HANDLE_SAVE,
    data
  };
}

export function handleSaveSuccess() {
  return {
    type: HANDLE_SAVE_SUCCESS
  };
}

export function handleSaveFailed(error) {
  return {
    type: HANDLE_SAVE_FAILED,
    error
  };
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

import {
  LOAD_DATA, LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS, LOAD_DATA_FAILED,
  HANDLE_SAVE,
  HANDLE_SAVE_SUCCESS,
  HANDLE_SAVE_FAILED
} from './constants';

const initialState = fromJS({
  formData: undefined,
});


function formDataReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_DATA:
      return state;

    case LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return state.set('formData', action.formData);

    case LOAD_DATA_FAILED:
      return state.set('errormsg', fromJS(action.errormsg));

    case HANDLE_SAVE:
      return state.set('data', action.data);

    case HANDLE_SAVE_SUCCESS:
      return state.set('message', action.message);

    case HANDLE_SAVE_FAILED:
      return state.set('errormsg', fromJS(action.errormsg));

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**saga.js**

```
import { takeEvery, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {
  LOAD_DATA,
  LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
  LOAD_DATA_FAILED,
  HANDLE_SAVE,
  HANDLE_SAVE_SUCCESS,
  HANDLE_SAVE_FAILED
} from './constants';


export function* getFormDataWorker() {
  try {
    const formData = yield call(api);
    if (formData) {
      yield put({ type: LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS, formData });
    }
  } catch (errormsg) {
    yield put({ type: LOAD_DATA_FAILED, errormsg });
  }
}

//  watcher
export function* formDataWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(LOAD_DATA, getFormDataWorker);
}


export function* saveDataWorker(action) {
  try {
    const message = yield call(savedata, action.data);
    if (message) {
      yield put({ type: HANDLE_SAVE_SUCCESS, message });
    }
  } catch (errormsg) {
    yield put({ type: HANDLE_SAVE_FAILED, errormsg });
  }
}

//  watcher
export function* saveDataWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(HANDLE_SAVE, saveDataWorker);
}


// All sagas to be loaded
export default [
  saveDataWatcher,
  formDataWatcher,
];
```

**Modal.js**

```
const Modal = ({data, handlePost}) => (
   { data ? data.map(item => (
      <input type="text" value={item.id} />
    )

   }
   <Button type="submit" onClick={handlePost}/ >

)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but it doesn't cover my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Remove the usage of localstorage
- On `componentDidUpdate` dispatch an action that sets the `itemId` in the Redux store.

  `componentDidUpdate() {
      this.props.setItemId({itemId: this.props.item.itemId})
  }`
- On form submit, dispatch the same action as you are currently using to trigger the saga.
- Change your `makeSelectModifiedData` selector to return the `itemId` you are storing in Redux now.